# mongoose schema string type is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I used mongoose to create a schema that contains an array field called "favoriteFoods". But when I retrieved an instance and tried to push another food to this array, it failed and says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".
I looked up the type of this field, it showed "undefined" instead of "array". Why is it happening?

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
age: Number,
favoriteFoods: [String] //set up the type as an array of string
});

const Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

new Person({ name: "Lily", age: 5, favoriteFoods: "Vanilla Cake" }).save().catch(e => {
console.log(e);
})

Person.find({ name: "Lily" }, (err, data) => {
if (err) console.log(err);
console.log(data); // it gives me the object
console.log(data.favoriteFoods); // undefined
console.log(typeof (data.favoriteFoods)); // undefined
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are saying `favoriteFoods` takes an array of strings, but you are passing it a string value NOT in an array. What's more, there is also no guarantee that your `new Person` is done being saved before you try to `find` it since the operation happens asynchronously

Comment: Thank you!!! I tried to change the value to an array and tried the async function but it's still not working...                                                                                                   `const findLily = async () => {
        const lily = new Person({ name: "Lily", age: 5, favoriteFoods: ["Vanilla Cake", "Lollipop"] });
    await lily.save();
    const found = await Person.find({ name: "Lily" });
    console.log(found);
    console.log(found.favoriteFoods);
    console.log(typeof (found.favoriteFoods));
}

findLily();`

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved!

I made 2 changes -

1. Passing an array to `favoriteFoods` instead of a single value (Thank you @pytth!!)
2. Changing Model.find() to Model.findOne() because the 1st returned an array but the 2nd one returned an object

So the final code is:

```
const findLily = async () => {
    const lily = new Person({ name: "Lily", age: 5, favoriteFoods: ["Vanilla Cake", "Lollipop"] });
    await lily.save();
    const found = await Person.find({ name: "Lily" });
    found.favoriteFoods.push("hamburger");
    await found.save();
}
```

Please correct me if I made any mistakes. Thanks! :)